# Add extra charge if gift messge with checkbox added on Cart Page in magento 2

Tags: shopping-cart, magento-2.1.7, giftmessage

I want to add one checkbox for the Gift wrap with Gift Message on Cart Page. If checkbox is enable then want to add extra fee to order. Please give me some solution.

Comment: are you able to acheive this ? i am looking for a same implementation

Comment: Did youn find a solution for that ?